# Visual Studio 2010 - Power Tools: Move Line Up Not Working

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was absolutely loving the Alt+Up Arrow in VS 2010 Pro Power tools. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/view/Discussions/all

Right now I can't get it to work and I'm not sure how to map it back myself. It could even be that ReSharper is getting involved.

If you can help me, I love you. I am a broken man without Move Line Up/Down

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things to verify:

1. Pro power tools is not Disabled.
2. There is an issue with Non-english Version of  Visual Studio. Are you using a non-English version of VS.
3. Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard `Edit.MoveLineUp` and `Edit.MoveLineDown` are they mapped to Alt+up/Alt+down arrows?

If all these are correct and still you don't get it working, please post your question in here:
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/814eb3c4-7d5e-4217-9711-e20117b20649/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem:

1. Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard
2. find Edit.MoveLineUp and Edit.MoveLineDown
3. change the default key combination to Alt+UpArrow and Alt+DownArrow, apply them

Answer (score 0):

Before vs2013, need to install an extension called `moveline` to make the key `alt + up` and `alt + down` work.